# D3 js scaleTime to 365 ~ 366 days in different years

Tags: d3.js

[d3.timeParse](https://github.com/d3/d3-time-format#locale_format) can parse the time format, but no matter how the format is set, the result contains the year, month, day, hour, minute, and second.

Like this: `Sat Jan 01 2020 00:00:00`

It can't only correspond to the month and day, if i want to use `d3.scaleTime ()` to scale to compare data of different years, how can I implement it?

```
For example:

===axis=======
x-axis: 12 month 366 day
y-axis: [max(value), mim(value)]

===data=======
data 1: 2016 = [{ date:2016/01/01,value=18},{ date:2016/01/02,value=199},...,{ date:2016/12/31,value=27}] (366 day)

data 2: 2017 = [{ date:2017/01/01,value=58},{ date:2017/01/02,value=9},...,{ date:2017/12/31,value=217}] (365 day)

data 3: 2018 (365 day)
.
.
data n: 2020  (366 day)
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. A date/time always contains the date and time. You can choose to only display the date or time if you like

Comment: @Mikkel I edited.

Comment: Still don\t understand what your problem is

Comment: Scale different years into the same year.